# Display full line with CharTermAttribute in Lucene

Tags: java, lucene

I have some e-books in `.txt` format where usually their page has the author, their title in the form (author: blah blah, title: blah blah etc.).

I want `Lucene` to automatically locate this information and then display it on the screen with the offset from the found term. More specifically i want to display:

```
BOOK1, (1)title: blah blah(15)  offset 1->15 , (16)author: blah blah(32) offset 16-32 , release date: 14/12/1923 32->50
```

However, what I do below in the code is to insert in the `displayTokensWithFullDetails` the file I want to find, and it only shows me when it finds the word author in the text And its Offset counter,
while I want to show me the whole line of the title with cumulative Offset that is from the first letter of the line to the last one. Is there any way I can display the whole line and the offset corresponding to the line?

I would describe it as a command that says *"Find a token in the text which matched in "title/author "etc and display the whole line with its offset."*

Unless there is a completely different way to do it than through the attributes of StandardAnalyzer.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.TokenStream;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.tokenattributes.CharTermAttribute;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.tokenattributes.OffsetAttribute;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.tokenattributes.PositionIncrementAttribute;




    public class Indexer 
    {

       public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

           File f= new File("C:/test1.txt");
           displayTokensWithFullDetails(f);
     }

 public static void displayTokensWithFullDetails(File F,String info)throws IOException {
 TokenStream stream = new StandardAnalyzer().tokenStream("contents",new FileReader(F));
 CharTermAttribute term = stream.addAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class); 
 PositionIncrementAttribute posIncr =
 stream.addAttribute(PositionIncrementAttribute.class);
 OffsetAttribute offset =
 stream.addAttribute(OffsetAttribute.class);
 int position = 0;
 stream.reset(); 
 while(stream.incrementToken()) 
 {

    String term1 = term.toString();

       if (term1.equals("title"))          
    {
       System.out.print("" +term1 + ":" +offset.startOffset() + "->" +offset.endOffset());

    }

        if (term1.equals("author"))          
    {
       System.out.print("" +term1 + ":" +offset.startOffset() + "->" +offset.endOffset());

    }

         if (term1.equals("release"))          
    {
       System.out.print("" +term1 + ":" +offset.startOffset() + "->" +offset.endOffset());

    }

 }
 stream.close();
 System.out.println();

}
```

Comment: So, you are using Lucene, but you don't actually want to use it to index or search? You are just using it to tokenize a string?

Comment: @femtoRgon if there is another way to use lucene to find the info that i want , i would like to know. But in this code i am using just for tokenizing